# Magento 2 - Query Builder

Tags: magento2, query, search-criteria

I need to create a query with searchCriteriaBuilder with this condition:

`WHERE visibility = [value] AND status = [value] AND ((category_id = [value] AND designer = [value]) OR (category_id = [value]))`

How can create this type of query using: FilterBuilder, FilterGroupBuilder and SearchCriteriaBuilder?